# ChromeWorker to write a huge file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my extension, I need to write a huge file (say around 20 gigs) to the disk. Currently I am doing it in the main thread, but file creation is very expensive operation. I was about to move the whole file creation process to a ChromeWorker, but based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers I cannot have access to the nsiFile from a ChromeWorker.

So my questions are:
1. Is it possible to access Cc, Ci, and Cu from within a ChromeWorker?
2. If not what would be the most efficient way to create and fill large files in Firefox. Note that I need to write the file based on segments and offsets (Ci.nsISeekableStream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access nsIFile from ChromeWorker. But nsIFile is horrible synchronus option.

Go with OS.File: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm

On that page go to the link for usage on workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_workers

On the mainthread os.file returns promises.

In worker they are synchronus. Wrap your os.file functions in worker with a try-catch, as when an error occurs, (like os.file.remove with option of ignoreAbsent set to false) then the catch will hold the OS.File.Error object.

Great move to ChromeWorker btw! I'm a huge fan of ChromeWorkers. I wrote a simple example of jsm using chromeworker here: https://github.com/Noitidart/jpm-chromeworker

For segments, you'll have to OS.File.open and then on the return value do a `.setPosition()` then you can read certain number of bytes from that position, or write, or whatever. Its awesome stuff. OS.File is the new way and the recommended way to do file operations. Its been around awhile now though since like Firefox 29 or before that.